customize header pandas to html
I created a web application to search content in CSV files.for now i only able to put all content into 1 column with comma as delimiter ,
I want to display the data as shown in the image.
My python code
selected_columns = [202, 9, 10, 135, 13, 127, 126, 26, 28,128,129,31,33]
df = df.iloc[:, selected_columns]
df.columns = ['CDRID', 'ANumber', 'To', 'SipStatus', 'ISrcIP', 'IDstIP', 'ISrcRTP', 'IDstRTP', 'OSrcIP', 'ODstIP', 'OSrcRTP', 'ODstRTP']]
df['Ingress'] = df[['ISrcIP', 'IDstIP', 'ISrcRTP', 'IDstRTP']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df['Egress'] = df[[ 'OSrcIP', 'ODstIP', 'OSrcRTP', 'ODstRTP']].apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
df = df.drop(columns=['ISrcIP', 'IDstIP', 'ISrcRTP', 'IDstRTP', 'OSrcIP', 'ODstIP', 'OSrcRTP', 'ODstRTP'])    
df = df.drop(columns=['ISrcIP', 'IDstIP', 'ISrcRTP', 'IDstRTP', 'OSrcIP', 'ODstIP', 'OSrcRTP', 'ODstRTP'])
combined_df = pd.concat([combined_df, df], ignore_index=True)
results.append(('Combined Results', combined_df.to_html(index=False)))

html frontend code
        {% for file, table in results %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
            {{ table|safe }}
        </table>
    </div>
{% endfor %}

current output

expected html header


Well, you are combining those IPs into a single column, so naturally they wouldn't show up as separate columns. Maybe don't combine them like that, and work from there.

You can use multi-index to have several levels of column headers and you can use .style.set_table_styles to customize the display of the dataframe:
cols = ['CDRID', 'ANumber', 'To', 'SipStatus', 'ISrcIP', 'IDstIP', 'ISrcRTP', 'IDstRTP', 
        'OSrcIP', 'ODstIP', 'OSrcRTP', 'ODstRTP']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.round(100*np.random.random((3, 12))), columns=cols)

# Use multi-index
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([4*[""] + 4*["Ingress"] + 4*["Outgress"], df.columns])

# Add borders and hide the index
df_styled = df.style.set_table_styles([
     {"selector": "td", "props": [("border", "1px solid black")]},  # cells borders
     {"selector": "th", "props": [("border", "1px solid black")]},  # headers borders
     {"selector": "th", "props": [("text-align", "center")]},  # text headers alignment
])
display(df_styled.hide(axis="index"))
# print(df_styled.to_html())  # to get the HTML/CSS code


